# prove that MN is a characteristic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that M,N characteristic in G implies that MN is characteristic in G.

How do I prove this? Not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$M,N\,\operatorname{char} G\Longrightarrow \phi(M)=M\,,\,\phi(N)=N\,\,\,\,\forall\,\phi\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$$

so

$$\forall\,mn\in MN\,\,,\,\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)\in MN\Longrightarrow \phi(MN)\subset MN$$

and this is enough (why?)

Comment: Why is this enough? I get all the steps but how does this prove that MN is characteristic, don't you need to show that $\phi(MN)=MN$, not just a subset?

Comment: Apply $\,\phi^{-1}\,$...:)

Comment: Ahhh I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start: If $\phi$ is an automorphism of $G$, then for any $mn \in MN$ (where $m \in M$ and $n \in N$) we have $\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)$. Try to show that $\phi(MN) = \phi(M)\phi(N)$ and use this to prove the result.